# How do I create a coroutine in VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to learn a bit about coroutines - and as such I just want to create some simple examples to mess around with.

What do I need to define in order to simply declare a short coroutine such as:

```
int my_fn(int i) { co_yield i; co_yield i<<1; co_yeild i*i; }
```

I'm getting errors from VS 2017 about no promise type for the above co routine definition.

Do I really need to provide a `std::experimental::coroutine_traits<int, ...>`?

I would have thought that such a thing would be generated on my behalf.  Obviously not!  Or I'm failing to configure the VS project properly in some way?

Comment: A coroutine needs to return a `generator<int>` or the like. VS provides an implementation of `generator` in `<experimental/generator>` IIRC.

Comment: Okay, I found that - but I don't see how to use that either.  the only operators on generator<int> are begin() and end() - but I'm expecting that to output one value per call - not a range...  ((confused))